# Shell script works in bash but not on 'adb shell'

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

Below shell script works perfectly fine in bash shell. But produces an error in android shell. May be it has got to do something with the shell that android is using. But how can I resolve it? If not a perfect solution, an hack would also do for me.

Shell-script :

```
func()
{
    local x
    x=${1:3:1}
    echo "x - $x"
    if [ "${x}" = " " -o -z "${x}" ]; then
      a="M"
    else
      a="S"
    fi
    echo "A - ${a} X - {x}"
}

func "abc=efg"
```

O/p In android shell,

```
root:/ # sample.sh                                                  
x - =
/system/bin/sample.sh[14]: [: =: missing second argument
A - S X - {x}
```

O/p on bash shell(Linux):

```
PC:~$ ./sample.sh 
x - =
A - S X - {x}
```

Comment: Does the script begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Barmar yes. It begins with #!/bin/bash on bash shell and #!/system/bin/sh on Android shell

Comment: What's the version of bash on Android?

Comment: @Barmar I think Android does not use bash. There is no executable /system/bin/bash

Comment: @Barmar the line "= = =" is creating the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb shell regular expression doesn't work as tested locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196302/adb-shell-regular-expression-doesnt-work-as-tested-locally)

Comment: @AlexP. He's not doing a regular expression match.

Comment: @Barmar So? My answer to the question I linked applies to this one as well.

Comment: @AlexP. The answer there doesn't show how to fix anything, it just says that some bash-specific things don't work. But there's nothing bash-specific in the line that's getting the error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `$x` is just `=`, it looks like:

```
if [ = = " " -o -z = ]; then
```

and it's apparently getting confused by the `=` that should be a value rather than an operator.

Change it to:

```
if [ "x${x}" = "x " -o "x${x}" = "x" ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I shall try it in some while and will get back to you. Bdw is there a way that we can find the shell type of Android shell?

Comment: Not sure. From what I've been able to find, it looks like it's something specific to ADB.

Comment: It seems it is mksh shell. Alex has just now added a link in the comment section of question. I will check more..

Comment: Hi Barmar, my troubles continue.. printf is not working as expected on mksh.. I posted a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668399/using-prinf-in-android-shell-mksh Please check if possible

Comment: I don't know anything about `mksh`, I'm not sure how I can help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

The adb shell was a direct descendant of BSD ash, of which dash is also.
The adb shell in more [recent android versions is mksh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844732/6843677) [standard shell of non-emulator builds on Android 4.0 and newer](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm#otheros).

From the error text it is probable that the shell is some mksh version.

As the mksh in android is under heavy changes and improvements, I recommend you to take dash as the target shell. It is available in most linux distributions and is the default system shell for debian and derivatives. It has less features but it is very difficult that something that work in dash will not work in the mksh of adb.

## {1:3:1}

In particular, this expression:

```
x=${1:3:1}
```

has no meaning in dash (it does work, however, in mksh). It could be replaced with this:

```
x=${1#???}; x=${x%"${x#?}"}
```

A bit longer, but gets the job done in **any** shell.

## [

Also, there is a problem with the `[…]` test, it seems to have too many "parts" to be reliable. Dividing the test into two (or more if needed) is the usual remedy:

```
if [ "${x}" = " " ] || [ -z "${x}" ]; then
```

The `||` is also an or (with the same preference as `&&`, the and).
Which also works in any shell.

With a final change of (a missing $ for variable x):

```
 echo "A - ${a} X - ${x}"
```

We get the whole script as:

```
func()
{
    local x
    x=${1#???}; x=${x%${x#?}}
    echo "x - $x"
    if [ "${x}" = " " ] || [ -z "${x}" ]; then
      a="M"
    else
      a="S"
    fi
    echo "A - ${a} X - ${x}"
}

func "abc=efg"
```

And running it in dash, bash or mksh, gives:

```
x - =
A - S X - =
```