# Using "printf" for hex values in android shell

Tags: android, linux, shell, mksh, toybox

I am porting my shell script (quite big shell script) from bash to android shell (mksh shell).

In Android, `printf` does not seem to be working the same way as it works in other Linux systems.

### Sample code :

```
$ cat sample.sh 
...
func1()
{
    A=100
    HEXA=`printf "%04x" ${A}`
    echo "A - ${A} HEXA - ${HEXA}"
}

func1
```

### This function's output is as follows.

```
$ ./sample.sh
A - 100 HEXA - 300000078
```

It is printing a really weird number.

I saw from other posts and from the manpage of `mksh` that `printf` is not recommended to be used in `mksh`. My shell script, which is quite big, is using it very heavily. So, I want to handle this somehow. What are my options to handle this?

Comment: do `readlink -f $(whence printf)`. if your android is recent enough it would link to `toybox`

Comment: @AlexP. Yes it is referring to toybox and issue turned out to be in toybox. The issue is fixed now. I pasted details in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why so many down votes without any related commments?

Comment: my guess would be that using a popular tag like `bash` brought over some people, who then did not find anything `bash` related in the question and felt like they wasted their time

Comment: Not an issue in `mksh` as it’s not built with `printf` as builtin. But I’ll clarify the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing `printf` in `toybox` is great.

But in case anyone would like to print out a number converted to *hex* (or pretty much any other reasonable *base* from `2` to `36` if they would be so inclined) on an *unrooted* device with the old `toybox` (or no `toybox` at all) - here is a way how to do it using `typeset` built-in of `mksh`:

```
baseconv(){ typeset -Ui${3:-16} -Z35 x=$1; echo ${x: -${2:-8}};}

func1()
{
    A=100
    HEXA=$(baseconv $A 4 16)
    echo "A - ${A} HEXA - ${HEXA}"
}
```

or just make a specific function for the `printf "%04x"` case:

```
printf04x(){ typeset -Ui16 -Z7 x=$1; echo ${x: -4};}

func1()
{
    A=100
    echo "A - ${A} HEXA - $(printf04x $A)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

printf in Android is linking to toybox

```
root:/ # which printf
/system/bin/printf
root:/ # ls -l /system/bin/printf
lrwxr-xr-x root     shell             2016-11-14 21:02 printf -> toybox
```

So the issue turned out to be in toybox printf.

The issue is now fixed - https://github.com/landley/toybox/issues/54