# od output format on Android phone

Tags: android, od, toybox

I'm trying to inspect a binary on my Android handset. The handset is rooted
and I'm talking to it through adb.

The first few bytes of the file in question show as

```
37777776620  042577  043114  000401  000001  000000  000000  000000  000000
37777776620  000003  000050  000001  000000  030614  000000  000064  000000
37777776620  110444  000001  000000  002400  000064  000040  000011  000050
37777776620  000034  000033  000006  000000  000064  000000  000064  000000
37777776620  000064  000000  000440  000000  000440  000000  000004  000000
37777776620  000004  000000  000003  000000  000524  000000  000524  000000
```

with a command line of

```
od <filename> | head
```

The bytes are correct, but what is this 37777776620 business ? It's supposed to
be the byte offset, so why the weird number, and why is it the same on every line ?

The hex equivalent of that number is fffffd90

od is a symbolic link to toybox. I've looked there as well, with no results.
When I copy the file to my Windows7 unit, I get the correct offsets from 00000000.

I thought that od was just supposed to take a linear stream of bytes and count them from 0 at the beginning of the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668399/using-printf-for-hex-values-in-android-shell

Comment: @AlexP. So, it's a bug in toybox. I've only just installed it, so don't know why it's still unpatched. Anyway, please make your comment an answer, and I'll upvote it.