# Why can "$path"/{,.}* include ".*" in its results?

Tags: shell, sh, glob

I have a bash script where I loop over all files in a directory using

```
for x in "$path/"{.,}*; do
    do some stuff here  
done
```

This does loop over all the files and directories (this is what I want),
but it also gives me the file `.*` which does not exist.
I am using a terminal emulator on android, so it could be an error there.
I am looking for a shell solution as I don't have most of the "normal Linux" commands such as sed.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor, or add four-space indents before each line, for multi-line code blocks.

Comment: That said, your goal is just to make sure that hidden files are included in the glob expression, right? Easier just to tell the shell that that's what you want.

Comment: (That said, `.*` will always have matches on standard Linux filesystems -- even if those matches are only the directories `.` and `..` -- so I'm curious about your platform where you're getting a contrary result)

Comment: ...that said -- is your shell **really** bash, or is it something like busybox ash (which supports only real POSIX sh syntax, without bash extensions)? Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950131/android-adb-shell-ash-or-ksh, it looks like it's probably either ash or mksh, **not** bash. If that's the case, you should probably adjust the question's tagging.

Comment: as for the {} button or indentations, thanks, I only had a textbox no editor buttons, I'll try to remember the four indentations. Indeed I also want hidden files, platform is a terminal emulator app, whith a subset of posix bash (if that is the correct term) I had to write my own basename for example

Comment: "POSIX sh" is the standard specifying baseline shell functionality. bash is a *specific implementation* of a large superset of that standard, written by Chet Ramey as part of the GNU project. (basename, btw, is *not* part of bash itself, but is a [POSIX-specified utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/basename.html) that an OS that wants to claim POSIX-compliance should provide; that said, I also consider it pretty useless -- `result=${var##*/}` is far faster to execute than `result=$(basename "$var")`, after all, and uses only builtin functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If Your Shell Is Really Bash *<sub>(as the question originally stated)</sub>*

Running the following command:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

will disable the default behavior of leaving globs with no matches unexpanded. Note that this can have surprising side effects: With `nullglob` set, `ls -l *.NotFilenamesHaveThisSuffix` will be exactly the same as `ls -l`.

---

That said, you can do even better:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for x in "$path/"*; do
    printf 'Processing file: %q\n' "$x"  
done
```

will, on account of setting `dotglob`, find all hidden files *without* needing the `{.,}` idiom at all, and will also have the benefit of consistently ignoring `.` and `..`.

---

#### If Your Shell Is `ash` Or `mksh`

It's actually quite usual to find bash on an Android device. If you have a baseline POSIX shell, the following will be more robust.

```
for x in "$path"/* "$path"/.*; do
  [ -e "$x" ] || continue                      # skip files that don't exist
  basename=${x##*/}                            # find filename w/o path
  case $basename in "."|"..") continue ;; esac # skip "." and ".."

  echo "Processing $x" >&2
  : ...put your logic here...
done
```

Comment: I already used the -e solution, but I was hoping there would be a solution that would not include .* in the list. But I can work with this behaviour. I actually don't get the . and .. Could you explain why the .* might end up in the list?

Comment: It would end up in the list if there are no files that start with `.`, and your shell doesn't include `.` or `..` in output unconditionally (which would mean that shell *definitely* isn't bash, which will include those as results when globbing `.*`).

Comment: This is because the shell's default behavior when a glob doesn't match is leaving the non-matching pattern in place. That way, `ls -l *.txt` gives you `*.txt: no such file exists` instead of behaving exactly like `ls -l` with no arguments and showing a list of all files in the current directory even though none of them match the glob.

Comment: Keep in mind that curly brace expansion isn't globbing -- it happens whether or not such files exist. Thus, `{.,}*` is exactly the same as passing `.*` and `*` separately, and each of those is evaluated as an independent glob expression (and left in the argument list if it doesn't match).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you don't want `.*` in the list even when it doesn't expand to anything, the solution is to use a shell (like bash!) with `nullglob` support.

Comment: Thanks it is clear now, so thanks for updating the title